# Scala: understanding parametric polymorphism

Tags: scala, types, parametric-polymorphism

What is the difference between

```
def drop1[A](l: List[A]) = l.tail
```

and

```
def drop1(l: List[Int]) = l.tail
```

provided the usage looks something like

```
drop1(List(1,2,3))
```

?

When should one or the other be used and why? Whereas I can understand the second example, I don't really understand the purpose of the first one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's very simple really. Your first example refers to the concept of **generics**.

**Generics** have a simple goal, to make certain methods **generic**, e.g non-type dependant.

Lets look at this trivial example. Say I want to write a `drop1` method for `List`.

I can either write one for every single type:(slow, repetitive):

```
def drop1(l: List[Int]): List[Int] = l.tail // this only works for Int

def drop1(l: List[String]): List[String] = l.tail // this only works for String
```

You can see how you'd have to write the above for every single type. To overcome this, you have generics:

```
def drop1[A](l: List[A]): List[A] = l.tail // this works for any given type.
```

Which essentially says: Whatever the type contained in the List is, give me the tail.
Instead of writing thousands of variants of `drop1` for the virtually infinite number of types, I only need to write one.

Now in Scala, your implementation is best done with:

```
implicit class ListOps[A](val l: List[A]) extends AnyVal {
   def drop1: List[A] = l match {
     case head :: tail => tail
     case Nil => Nil
   }
}
// you can now have
List(1, 2, 3).drop1
```

It is also generally a bad idea to rename well known library methods. A `tail` operation is unsafe and a `drop` is safe. All you are causing is confusion, since there is a default `drop` method.

```
List(1, 2, 3) drop 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why exactly is the first `[A]` needed in my first example? Is it just a syntax requirement?

Comment: Yes, so compiler can distinguish type you're introducing from some already defined A type. Why would it? To prevent you from the mistakes and make your intent explicit.

Comment: Thanks. As the matter of fact it is while reading this tutorial I've raised this question.

Comment: A deeper reason (and in some eyes, the source of the word "parametric" in "parametric polymorphism") is called parametricity. Specifically, your `drop1` specialized to `Int` has fewer guarantees about what it can do. For example, it could look at the fifth int and if it's equal to 74, it could drop five elements instead of just one. The parametric one, in theory, knows nothing about the elements and can only operate on the structure of the list. Of course, Scala exposes JVM warts like `.isInstanceOf` to get around that, but in theory at least the parametric `drop1` is a tad more trustworthy.

Answer (score 3):

In short -- some operations do not depend on a specific type and can be abstracted. Counting apples and counting oranges is essentially the same operation. If you're going to reuse algorithm, it is way smarter to abstract some types away instead of writing

```
def countOranges(xs: List[Orange]) = { some code } 
def countApples(xs: List[Apple]) = { the very same code }
```

Answer (score 0):

My be little late , if you have an idea about generics in Java then analogy can be made here:-

**Java** --> generic class's object can be passed in method argument.

```
class Test<T> {
    // An object of type T is declared
    T obj;
    Test(T obj) {  this.obj = obj;  }  // constructor
    // some other methods in class 
}

Test<String> testobj = new Test<String>();

public void function(testobj){ 
// do something with testobj 
}
```

**Scala**  --> Same way generic parametric functions work in scala. Here, [A] defines the generic Type in scala

```
def drop1[A](l: List[A]) = l.tail
```

usage of above function:-

```
scala>drop1(List(1,2,3))   // output List(2, 3)
scala>drop1(List(1.0,2.0,3.0)) // output List(2.0, 3.0)
scala>drop1(List('a','b','c'))  // output List(b, c)
```

Explanation:- Just pass any type of List it works like a charm.The syntax is like below:-

```
def function[Type](param:Type):Type = {do something}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//snippet to explain scala parametric polymorphism

object MethodParametricPolymorphism {
  //parametric polymorphism is similar/same as of java generics
  def countOranges(oranges : List[Orange]) = oranges.size;
  def countApples(apples : List[Apple]) = apples.size
  //if algo is same then paramatric polymorphism can be used
  def count[A](items : List[A]) = items.size

  val oranges : List[Orange] =  List( new Orange(1.1))
  val apples : List[Apple] =  List( new Apple(2.1), new Apple(2.2))

  countOranges(oranges);
  countApples(apples);
  //using polymorphic typed method
  count(oranges);
  count(apples);

  case class Orange ( weight: Double)
  case class Apple ( weight: Double)
 }
```