# Traits and method parameters in Scala

Tags: scala

What is this called in Scala? Is this considered polymorphism?

Say I have a old method like this:

```
def close(pair: TradingPair, currentDate: LocalDate, startTime: Long): Unit = {
    ...

    if (rowsWritten > 0) ZipWriter.compressAndDeleteOriginals(file)
    else file.delete()
  }
```

But I want it to be this:

```
def close(pair: TradingPair, currentDate: LocalDate, startTime: Long, writer: CompressionWriter): Unit = {
     ...

    if (rowsWritten > 0) writer.compressAndDeleteOriginals(file)
  }
```

because I anticipate more types of compression writers. Is a good way to go about this to do this:

```
trait CompressionWriter {...}
object ZipWriter extends CompressionWriter {...}
object GZipWriter extends CompressionWriter {...}
```

Can I use the type of the new trait in the method argument of `close`?

Is this considered polymorphism in Scala?

Comment: yes you can. if they share same behaviors you abstract them as a trait.

Comment: Can you give a more fleshed out answer and I'll give you credit? What is this called in Scala? Got any documentation to share?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you define stuffs who share common trait, is a one kind of polymorphism simply called [Subtype polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping).

Example,

```
scala> trait Compressor { def compress(data: String): String }
defined trait Compressor

scala> class Zipper extends Compressor { def compress(data: String) = s"$data is zip compressed" }
defined class Zipper

scala> class GZipper extends Compressor { def compress(data: String) = s"$data is gzip compressed" }
defined class GZipper
```

a method that takes trait as a parameter,

```
scala> def compress (data: String, compressor: Compressor) = compressor.compress(data)
compress: (data: String, compressor: Compressor)String

scala> compress("i want to compress", new Zipper)
res1: String = i want to compress is zip compressed
```

The other polymorphism in scala are ;

1. Parametric Polymorphism - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21115651/432903
2. Ad-hoc Polymorphism - http://blog.jaceklaskowski.pl/2015/05/15/ad-hoc-polymorphism-in-scala-with-type-classes.html

You can study coursera class week 3 (Data and Abstraction) for concept - https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1/home/week/3